# Upgrading Android App to MvvmCross 6.4.1 Causes Build to Fail on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, upgrade, mvvmcross, build-error

As the title indicates, I am in the process of upgrading the dependencies of an existing Xamarin.Android project. The Android project uses MvvmCross for much of the cross-platform code (we support other platforms as well). As part of this upgrade, we are moving from MvvmCross 6.2.2 to 6.4.1.

After upgrading the libraries, however, the project is no longer builds as expected when building with Visual Studio 2017. The error message I get is shown below. I have tried cleaning & rebuilding to no avail. The project builds with Visual Studio 2019, but experiences strange behavior; this has happened even before upgrading our dependencies.

Any suggestions on possible ways to fix this would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

```
The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1' (defined in assembly 'MvvmCross, Version=6.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') with scope 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() RadResponder.Mobile.UI.Droid
```

Comment: MvvmCross 6.4.1 is built with VS2019 and we can't guarantee that it works with older versions of VS. If you can describe the strange behavior, I think that would be better to focus on and fix.

Comment: Fair enough point! I've made another post detailing that issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58668270/listitems-in-mvxlistview-bind-inconsistently-with-items-in-mvvmcross-6-4-1-after

Please let me know if you need any other additional information

Comment: @Cheesebaron I got exactly the same issue when building with VS2017 on build server. Do you have any ideas if there are any workarounds for it? Or maybe you can give some context about this error?

Comment: @CurtisCali  I have also encountered with same issue. build is failing on vs2017. VS upgrade is the only option I have or is there any other solution you have?

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade from MvvmCross 6.3.1 to MvvmCross 6.4.1 and using VS 2017 we also have simialr error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type
>   with token 01000113 from typeref (expected class
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1' in assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e') 
>   assembly:mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
>   type:System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1 member:(null) occurred

Could not resolve type with token 01000113 from typeref (expected class 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1' in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e') assembly:mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e type:System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1 member:(null)

```
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Binding.MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.InitializeContextStack () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Android\Binding\MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs:273 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Binding.MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.RegisterPlatformSpecificComponents () [0x0000c] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Android\Binding\MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs:268 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.MvxCoreBindingBuilder.DoRegistration () [0x00048] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Binding\MvxCoreBindingBuilder.cs:36 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingBuilder.DoRegistration () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Binding\MvxBindingBuilder.cs:16 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Binding.MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.DoRegistration () [0x00012] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Android\Binding\MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs:32 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Core.MvxAndroidSetup.InitializeBindingBuilder () [0x0000d] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Android\Core\MvxAndroidSetup.cs:164 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Core.MvxAndroidSetup.InitializeLastChance () [0x00006] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Android\Core\MvxAndroidSetup.cs:151 
  at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup.InitializeSecondary () [0x0017a] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Core\MvxSetup.cs:132 
  at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton+<<StartSetupInitialization>b__13_0>d.MoveNext () [0x0001c] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Core\MvxSetupSingleton.cs:187 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton.EnsureInitialized () [0x0006e] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Core\MvxSetupSingleton.cs:116 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.EnsureSetupInitialized (MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views.IMvxAndroidView androidView) [0x0001c] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Android\Views\MvxActivityViewExtensions.cs:154 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.OnViewCreate (MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views.IMvxAndroidView androidView, Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00014] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Android\Views\MvxActivityViewExtensions.cs:39 
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views.MvxActivityAdapter.EventSourceOnCreateCalled (System.Object sender, MvvmCross.Base.MvxValueEventArgs`1[T] eventArgs) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Platforms\Android\Views\MvxActivityAdapter.cs:76 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1[MvvmCross.Base.MvxValueEventArgs`1[Android.OS.Bundle]].invoke_void_object_TEventArgs(object,MvvmCross.Base.MvxValueEventArgs`1<Android.OS.Bundle>)
  at MvvmCross.Base.MvxDelegateExtensions.Raise[T] (System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] eventHandler, System.Object sender, T value) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Base\MvxDelegateExtensions.cs:18 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat.EventSource.MvxEventSourceAppCompatActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00014] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross.Android.Support\V7.AppCompat\EventSource\MvxEventSourceAppCompatActivity.cs:33 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat.MvxAppCompatActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross.Android.Support\V7.AppCompat\MvxAppCompatActivity.cs:88 
  at ITG.Brix.Mobile.EOrder.Views.Activities.LoginActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00002] in C:\Projects\Git\native-eorder\ITG.Brix.Mobile.EOrder\Views\Activities\LoginActivity.cs:25
```