# ListItems in MvxListView bind inconsistently with Items in MvvmCross 6.4.1 after Upgrading

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.android, upgrade, mvvmcross

As the title indicates, I am in the process of upgrading the dependencies of an existing Xamarin.Android project. The Android project uses MvvmCross for much of the cross-platform code (we support other platforms as well). As part of this upgrade, we are moving from MvvmCross 6.2.2 to 6.4.1. We are currently building the app with Visual Studio 2019.

However, after upgrading, I have noticed that many of my project's layouts no longer bind under  as consistently as they did when running. For many of our views on Android, we use MvxListView to render a list of form cells for the user to enter input. Under Mvx 6.2.2 built with Visual Studio 2017, the lists rendered as expected. However, when building with Visual Studio 2019 & Mvx 6.4.1 some items appeared to bind and others did not. I have ruled out Mvx 6.4.1 as the cause because I have tried compiling our app, unmodified, with both VS 2017 & 2019, and have still gotten inconsistent binding on VS 2019.

If if you guys have any suggestions on what to fix, I would love to hear it!

Some Android Build properties:

[image: Options 1]
[image: Options 2]

To illustrate what I mean by inconsistent binding:

Consistent binding:
[image: Consistent Binding]

Iconsistent Binding:
[image: Inconsistent Binding]
Some snippets of code for the MvxAdapter subclass we use to render the individual rows:

```
private View _locationView;
        protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object source, ViewGroup parent, int templateId)
        {
            var item = source as ICellModel;
            if (item != null)
            {
                templateId = GetTemplateIdForCellType(item.CellType);
                templateId = GetStateCellForKey(item, templateId);
            }

            try
            {
                if (item != null && item.CellType != CellType.MapSelector)
                {
                    var bindableView = base.GetBindableView(convertView, source, parent, templateId);
                    return bindableView;
                }
                if (_locationView != null)
                {
                    return _locationView;
                }

                _locationView = base.GetBindableView(convertView, source, parent, templateId);
                return _locationView;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return null;
            }

        }

private int GetTemplateIdForCellType(CellType cellType)
        {
            // Example code to show picking a custom templace
            switch (cellType)
            {
                case CellType.X
                    return Resource.Layout.XCell;
                case CellType.Y:
                    return Resource.Layout.YCell;
                case CellType.Z:
                    return Resource.Layout.ZCell;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        private static int GetStateCellForKey(ICellModel cellModel, int templateId)
        {
            var singleLineEditCellsToBeDisplayCells = new List<int>
                {
                    .// Types for single line edit cells
                };
            var multiplineEditCellsToBeDisplayCells = new List<int>
            {
                // types for multi-line edit cells
            };
            if (cellModel.FormState == FormState.Display)
            {
                if (singleLineEditCellsToBeDisplayCells.Any(c => c.Equals(templateId)))
                    return Resource.Layout.SingleLineDisplayFormCell;
                else if (multiplineEditCellsToBeDisplayCells.Any(c => c.Equals(templateId)))
                    return Resource.Layout.MultiLineDisplayFormCell;
            }

            var selectorCellModel = cellModel as SelectorCellModel;
            if (selectorCellModel != null && selectorCellModel.IsMultiline)
            {
                return Resource.Layout.MultiLineSelectorCell;
            }


            //Multi line

            //Map cell
            return templateId;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Looks like something that could be migrated to MvxRecyclerView and MvxItemTemplateSelector. That would clean up this adapter so much. How are you binding the cells?

Comment: Hi Cheesebaron,

Sorry for getting back to you late. I've been busy IRL with various things.

So in our current MvxAdapter implementation, the bound view is created using an overriden GetBindableView method ([link](https://gist.github.com/curtiscali/c558001ef5bb890bb56f2c247ba114c0))

For more reference you can have a look at some sample layouts [here](https://gist.github.com/curtiscali/615498f288e2d4c1ca0bf6d6d81e02d3)

Comment: Please let me know if you need any other information!

Comment: I am more interested in whether you are changing any of the binding methods. The code you've shown here should be fine as long as the model set as binding data matches.

Comment: In that case I'm confused as to what your referring to by the term "binding method" I don't think I'm overriding/changing any of them. Could you give me examples of some MvxAdapter methods? As far as model set binding data matching, the models should be matched up appropriately with the views for binding, but I will have to verify that.

Comment: I think you need to move over to use MvxRecyclerView for lists with different item types. As is MvxAdapter is geared towards using one Item Template and you are probably running into an issue where it tries to reuse Views which you don't expect for that item position. See: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Binding/Views/MvxAdapter.cs#L205

Comment: Alright I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/android/android-recyclerview hopefully this piece of docs describes it well enough for you. Also take a look here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Droid/Resources/layout/CollectionView.axml and here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Droid/TemplateSelectors/AnimalTemplateSelector.cs

Comment: Thanks for the useful sources. As I said I'll give it a shot.

But in hindsight I realized my title was poorly worded. I've had this binding issue without making any MvvmCross upgrades when building with VS2019, Building with VS2017 and MvvmCross 6.2.2 works as expected.

To quote myself: "I have ruled out Mvx 6.4.1 as the cause because I have tried compiling our app, unmodified, with both VS 2017 & 2019, and have still gotten inconsistent binding on VS 2019."

Are you sure this RecyclerView fix would address that?

Comment: Hi, I'd like thank you for suggesting switching to MvxRecyclerView. I switched over and tested it on my un-upgraded code, and it fixed another known bug we had. So thank you very much for that.

However, testing this with my upgraded code did not solve the problem in the original post. Do you have any idea what else could possibly cause templates in an MvxRecyclerView to bind inconsistently?

Comment: I would need more insight into what you are doing. I.e. a repro sample, because I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Alright thanks. I think I'll get to work on creating a repro project. For NDA reasons I can't share the full source code of the project I'm working on. I'll link you to a github repo when I have one